# How can I sign in to Chrome but not immediately sync everything?

Tags: google-chrome, sync

I want to sign in to Chrome on a specific computer but not sync things to it from other computers or sync anything from other computers to it. Basically, I just want the account to be signed in. Whenever I sign in, however, it immediately starts sending and receiving all kinds of things (bookmarks, extensions, apps, etc). It is then I have to tell it to only do a selective sync and then clean up the mess it made.

How can I sign in but not sync things immediately? So far my only idea is to sign in then quickly disconnect from the Internet.

Comment: Sync is the primary reason why sign-in is available.  What other features are you getting from signing in?

Comment: Some extensions require you to be signed in in order for you to use them e.g. MightyText.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How can I sign in to Chrome but not immediately sync everything?

Use the following command line switch:

> `--disable-sync` Disables syncing browser data to a Google Account.

Source Reference [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

See [Run Chromium with flags](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags) for instructions on how to run chrome with added command line switches.