# How can I stop Chrome from syncing my extensions/apps every time?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-sync

I like to sign into Google Chrome when I use different computers, such as the computers in the library at my University campus.  Whenever I do so, Chrome automatically downloads and installs the extensions that I use at home.  Each one pops up a new tab, and it's a bit annoying.

There's an option in `chrome://settings` to specify what gets synced, and you can turn off 'Apps' and 'Extensions'.  The problem is that this setting doesn't seem to be at all persistent: when I sign in on a new computer, it's gone right back to 'Sync everything'.

How can I persistently change my sync settings so that Chrome never tries to sync apps and extensions?

**Note:** not  a duplicate of [How can I sign in to Chrome but not immediately sync everything?](https://superuser.com/questions/845000/how-can-i-sign-in-to-chrome-but-not-immediately-sync-everything?rq=1) : I don't want to turn off syncing for everything; I just want to turn off sync for certain things, and I'm confused why this setting does not seem to be persistent.

Comment: Is it possible to set that setting BEFORE you login?

Comment: @MichaelKohne It doesn't seem to be.  Sync settings don't make any sense if you're not logged into an account, so they don't show up till you log in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sign in to Chrome but not immediately sync everything?](https://superuser.com/questions/845000/how-can-i-sign-in-to-chrome-but-not-immediately-sync-everything)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/845000/how-can-i-sign-in-to-chrome-but-not-immediately-sync-everything?rq=1 has a command line option for chrome that looks like it should do the trick.